# Need help figuring out iOS 8 bug/glitch

Tags: debugging, ios7, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I have 2 view controllers in game App. 1st VC is no gameplay only intro. 2nd VC is gameplay and GameOver screen. On GameOver screen is a BACK button that takes you back to 1st VC. On GameOver is also Final score and High Score. Example, current Final score = 3 and previous game's Final score was 2. For some reason when I click BACK to go to 1st VC during that split second transition from VC2 to VC1, the Final score will show 2 instead of 3. That's NOT supposed to happen. However, this has NO affect on gameplay. But it's still an annoying bug/glitch.

finalscore = UILabel

Highscore =UILAbel

int scoreNumber;

NSInteger HighScoreNumber;

```
 -(void)GameOver{

 if (scoreNumber <0) {
    scoreNumber=0;
}

     finalscore.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Final Score:   %i", scoreNumber];

    if (scoreNumber >HighScoreNumber) {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:scoreNumber forKey:@"HighScoreSave"];

    Highscore.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Score:   %i", scoreNumber];
}

    HighScoreNumber=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"HighScoreSave"];

    Highscore.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Score:   %li", (long) HighScoreNumber];

   }
```

When I reach a new High Score, the same thing happens in VC2 to VC1 split second transition where it shows a previous high score instead of current high score. This glitch or bug ONLY happens in iOS 8 and NEVER in iOS 7.

I don't know how to fix this. What could be the issue?

I use MODAL unwind segue for going from VC1 to VC2 and back.

Comment: It is probably _your_ bug, not a system bug.

Comment: No, it's an iOS 8 bug possibly related to storyboard updating and re-arranging things due to constraints. I've found out on stack over flow, i'm not the only one with this issue.

Comment: Can you specify the bug so that I can reproduce it? That would be really cool. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're actually correct, it's a problem possibly on my end and not iOS 8 system problem even though it ONLY affects iOS 8. I edited in my code. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that's the issue, but I noticed you're not synchronizing `NSUserDefault`.

Try adding it:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:scoreNumber forKey:@"HighScoreSave"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]
```

Comment: I added the synchronize code but nothing changed. Still get my glitch/bug.